# Loading wordpress plugin on specific page only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin for wordpress that loads javascript in a page. 
But i want this plugin to load only on selected pages. Not all pages.
Can someone suggest how to do that? 
Here is the code.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'soundninja_enqueue');
function soundninja_enqueue($hook)
{
    wp_enqueue_script('soundninja', // id
        'http://soundninja.github.io/SNtest/build/Soundninja.min.js', // path
        array('jquery'), // dependencies
        0, // appends ?ver=$wordpress_version
        true // in_footer
    );
}
```

Comment: on a specific page, meaning a page with specific post id?

Comment: both! a specific page and a specific post id.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround would be to keep the plugin deactivated and activate it only for the required pages. This would prevent the additional overhead involved in loading the plugin on pages where the plugin is not required. And most importantly you do not have to tweak the code of the existing plugin.

Here is the post which can give you more idea http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/how-to-selectively-load-plugins-for-specific-pages

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you will call your function `soundninja_enqueue($hook)` you can easily add an `if` statement asking if the current page/post id is in an allowed list of ids.

But first you need to get the current page/post id, for this you have a couple of options, depending if are calling the function inside or outside of `The loop`.

see here on [how to get the current page id in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38226/get-post-id-in-wordpress-action)

```
<?php
$allowedIds = array(12,13,14);
if (in_array($currentID,$allowedIds)) soundninja_enqueue($hook);
```

Another option is to pass the the current page/post id as a parameter to the function and do the same `if` test inside the function, your choice.